# inTabOrder in MathJax not taking effect

Tags: mathjax

This is a follow-up question to [Override mathjax accessibility blue box feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986545/override-mathjax-accessibility-blue-box-feature). I'm playing around with `menuSettings` in MathJax. However, I can't seem to get `inTabOrder` to work. Here is my current MathJax config:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [['$', '$']],
      menuSettings: { inTabOrder: false }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [['$', '$']]
    },
    menuSettings: { inTabOrder: false }
  });
</script>
```

as the `menuSettings` block should be at the top level, not nested inside the `tex2jax` block.